Compounding a Poisson distribution with rate parameter distributed according to a gamma distribution yields a negative binomial distribution.
In my bachelor's thesis, I present a proof concerning the mixed Poisson distribution. My questions are, first, whether the proof is correct in terms of content and, second, whether it meets the formal standards of such a thesis. I have the impression that I might have formulated the theorem somewhat awkwardly.
Here is how I initially defined the mixed Poisson distribution:
Definition 2.6.1. Let $X$ be a random variable. $X$ follows a mixed Poisson distribution with density function $\pi(\lambda)$ if its probability mass function is given by
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}[X = k] = 
    \begin{cases} 
    \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} \pi(\lambda) \, d\lambda & \text{if } k \in \mathbb{N}_0, \\ 
    0 & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here, $\pi(\lambda)$ is the density function of a continuous random variable $\Lambda$ that takes values in the positive real numbers.
Here is the theorem and the proof I made for the mixture with a gamma-distributed parameter:
Theorem 2.6.4. Let $X$ be a random variable that follows a mixed Poisson distribution with the density function
$\pi(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta}} \quad \text{for } \lambda > 0,
$
where $\pi(\lambda)$ is the density function of a gamma-distributed random variable $\Lambda \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ with parameters $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$.
Then $X \sim \mathcal{NB}(\alpha, \frac{1}{\beta+1})$ is a negative binomially distributed random variable with parameters $\alpha > 0$ and $p = \frac{1}{\beta+1} \in (0, 1)$.
Proof.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[X = k] &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta}} \, d\lambda \\
&= \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^\infty \lambda^k e^{-\lambda} \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta}} \, d\lambda \\
&= \frac{1}{k! \Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha} \int_0^\infty \lambda^{k + \alpha - 1} e^{-\lambda\left(1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)} \, d\lambda.
\end{align}
Using the substitution $u = \lambda\left(1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)$ (so that $ \lambda = u \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\beta}} $ and $ d\lambda = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\beta}} du $), we have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[X = k] &= \frac{1}{k! \Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha} \int_0^\infty \left(u \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\beta}}\right)^{k + \alpha - 1} e^{-u} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\beta}} \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{k! \Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha} \left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\beta}}\right)^{k + \alpha} \int_0^\infty u^{k + \alpha - 1} e^{-u} \, du.
\end{align}
From the definition of the gamma function, $ \Gamma(k + \alpha) = \int_0^\infty u^{k + \alpha - 1} e^{-u} \, du $, it follows that:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[X = k] &= \frac{\Gamma(k + \alpha)}{k! \Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\beta}}\right)^{k + \alpha} \\
&= \binom{k + \alpha - 1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{\beta}{\beta + 1}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{\beta}{\beta + 1}\right)^k \\
&= \binom{k + \alpha - 1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{\beta + 1}\right)^\alpha \left(1 - \frac{1}{\beta + 1}\right)^k.
\end{align}
Thus, we obtain the probability mass function of a negative binomial random variable according to Definition 2.5.1, where $ p = \frac{1}{\beta + 1}$.

The proof seems good to me. Regarding the formulation of the statement, you could phrase it as follows:

[...] a mixed distribution with $\pi(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\beta}}$ being the density function of a gamma-distributed random variable [...].

Also, I would add a couple of commas here:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}[X = k] = 
    \begin{cases} 
    \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} \pi(\lambda) \, d\lambda, & \text{if } k \in \mathbb{N}_0, \\ 
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
